# Can I program animations in kivy language?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

## Goal:

- To know that if we can create animations using `kv` file.

---

## Question:

- Is it possible to create animations using `kv` language?

---

### Code:

```
#:import Animation kivy.animation.Animation
<MainClass>:
    Animation:
        duration: 4
        transition: 'in_quad'
        x: 45
        y: 45
```

---

### Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this syntax does not exist, and I'm not sure it even really makes sense.

You *can* create and start animations in kv language, e.g. in response to an event: `on_event: Animation(duration=4, x=45, transition="in_quad").start(self)` etc.

Comment: Using kv with sequential animation is possible?